# Marketing Cloud Journey Associate a Task by External ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I am creating a Journey which will create a Task on a Contact record in my Salesforce Sales Cloud.

The entry point for the Journey is a Data Extension loaded with data from an external source.  This data is loaded via CSV import.

The external source has access to the External ID that is stored on my Contact record in Sales Cloud, but it does not have access to the Sales Cloud Contact Record ID.

In theory, this should be possible if Marketing Cloud creates the Task by upsert with the External ID, but I can't determine if this is at all possible.

Has anyone completed a similar activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, by choosing the Find and Update option on the Task activity, you can select an attribute from your Contact Data to let Marketing Cloud identify the correct record.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This is actually what I was doing but because we are using PersonAccounts, when I tried to locate the Contact record it was pulling back the Account Id.  So when I attempted to associate the Task using what I thought was the Contact ID it was failing since it was actually the Account ID.  I fixed this by using the RelatesTo field for the lookup.